# Node Rest Client Response Error

Tags: json, node.js, rest, response

Can I handle a non-JSON response in **node-rest-client** POST method?

This is the error and response i'm getting:

> response: [PURGED], error: [SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at
>   position 0]

Can I somehow avoid getting an error? The function does what is requested.
I suppose creating a custom parser is a solution? I don't understand how to achieve it though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a "mimetypes" attribute to your client options.
For example, something like this should enable you to handle XML as well as JSON responses:

```
const Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
var client = new Client({mimetypes:{
    json:["application/json","application/json;charset=utf-8"],
    xml:["application/xml","application/xml;charset=utf-8"]
}});
client.post(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried that and it's still not working. I tried to add text:["text/plain","text/plain;charset=utf-8"] as well.